# How to Update rows value in a column only with one value

Tags: php, android, mysql

I wanna build a scanner on android, the scanned value will update the database in mysql on the column, but I wanna to update entire rows on that column that match scanned value, then update other column with text "matched value"

I find for solutions but never get this kind of problem's solution, usually only for updating single row in a column, (single cell).

Here is my Code in PHP :

```
<?php
include 'db/db_connect.php';
$response = array();

//Check for mandatory parameters
if(isset($_POST['scanned_text'])&&isset($_POST['movie_id'])){
$movieId = $_POST['movie_id'];
$scannedText = $_POST['scanned_text'];

//Query to update a movie
//$query = "SELECT movie_id from movies";
$query = "UPDATE movies SET scanned_text=? WHERE movie_id=?";
//Prepare the query
if($stmt = $con->prepare($query)){
    //Bind parameters
    $stmt->bind_param("si",$scannedText,$movieId);
    //Exceting MySQL statement
    $stmt->execute();
    //Check if data got updated
    if($stmt->affected_rows == 1){
        $response["success"] = 1;           
        $response["message"] = "Movie successfully updated";

    }else{
        //When movie is not found
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Movie not found";
    }                   
}else{
    //Some error while updating
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = mysqli_error($con);
}

}else{
//Mandatory parameters are missing
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "missing mandatory parameters";
}
//Displaying JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

I wannto set WHERE movie_id=scanned_text, then update other column value into "matched value" or something similar

Here is my android code

```
    package com.bani.loginandregistration;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bani.loginandregistration.helper.CheckNetworkStatus;
import com.bani.loginandregistration.helper.HttpJsonParser;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.CameraSource;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.Detector;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.Barcode;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.BarcodeDetector;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;



public class MovieUpdateDeleteActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String KEY_DATA = "data";
private static final String KEY_MOVIE_ID = "movie_id";
private static final String KEY_UPDATE_TIME = "update_time";
private static final String KEY_CUST_ORDER = "cust_order";
private static final String KEY_DOC_DATEAWAL = "doc_dateawal";
private static final String KEY_MOVIE_NAME = "movie_name";
private static final String KEY_GENRE = "genre";
private static final String KEY_DN_NO = "dn_no";
private static final String KEY_INV_NO = "inv_no";
private static final String KEY_REMARK = "remark";
private static final String KEY_TYPE = "type";
private static final String KEY_YEAR = "year";
private static final String KEY_SCANNED_TEXT = "scanned_text";
private static final String KEY_RATING = "rating";
private static final String KEY_MATERIAL_NUMBER = "material_number";
private static final String KEY_MATERIAL_NAME = "material_name";
private static final String KEY_CAR_TYPE = "car_type";
private static final String KEY_DN_DATEAWAL= "dn_dateawal";
private static final String KEY_SHIP_DATEAWAL = "ship_dateawal";
private static final String BASE_URL = "https://adm-parts.xyz/movies/";
//private static final String BASE_URL = 
"http://admspddatabase.000webhostapp.com/movies/";
//private static final String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.43.197/movies/";
private String movieId;
private EditText movieNameEditText;
private EditText genreEditText;
private EditText updateTimeEditText;
private EditText custOrderEditText;
private EditText docDateAwalEditText;
private EditText dnNoEditText;
private EditText invNoEditText;
private EditText remarkEditText;
private EditText typeEditText;
private EditText yearEditText;
private EditText ratingEditText;
private EditText materialNumberEditText;
private EditText materialNameEditText;
private EditText carTypeEditText;
private EditText dnDateAwalEditText;
private EditText shipDateAwalEditText;
private String scanned;
private String movieName;
private String updateTime;
private String custOrder;
private String docDateAwal;
private String genre;
private String dnNo;
private String invNo;
private String remark;
private String type;
private String year;
private String rating;
private String materialNumber;
private String materialName;
private String carType;
private String dnDateAwal;
private String shipDateAwal;
private int success;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;


SurfaceView surfaceView;
TextView txtBarcodeValue;
private CameraSource cameraSource;
private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 201;
String intentData = "";
boolean isEmail = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_movie_update_delete);


    Intent intent = getIntent();
    movieNameEditText = findViewById(R.id.txtMovieNameUpdate);
    genreEditText = findViewById(R.id.txtGenreUpdate);
    updateTimeEditText = findViewById(R.id.txtUpdateTimeUpdate);
    custOrderEditText = findViewById(R.id.txtCustOrderUpdate);
    docDateAwalEditText = findViewById(R.id.txtDocDateAwalUpdate);
    dnNoEditText = findViewById(R.id.txtDnNoUpdate);
    invNoEditText = findViewById(R.id.txtInvNoUpdate);
    remarkEditText = findViewById(R.id.txtRemarkUpdate);
    typeEditText = findViewById(R.id.txtTypeUpdate);
    yearEditText = findViewById(R.id.txtYearUpdate);
    ratingEditText = findViewById(R.id.txtRatingUpdate);
    materialNumberEditText = findViewById(R.id.txtMaterialNumberUpdate);
    materialNameEditText = findViewById(R.id.txtMaterialNameUpdate);
    carTypeEditText = findViewById(R.id.txtCarTypeUpdate);
    dnDateAwalEditText = findViewById(R.id.txtDnDateAwalUpdate);
    shipDateAwalEditText = findViewById(R.id.txtShipDateAwalUpdate);
    txtBarcodeValue = findViewById(R.id.txtBarcodeValue);

    movieId = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_MOVIE_ID);
    new FetchMovieDetailsAsyncTask().execute();

    initViews();

}

private void initViews() {
    CompoundButton scan = findViewById(R.id.switch_scan);
    txtBarcodeValue = findViewById(R.id.txtBarcodeValue);
    surfaceView = findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
    txtBarcodeValue.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    surfaceView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    scan.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new 
CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                surfaceView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                txtBarcodeValue.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                surfaceView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                txtBarcodeValue.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });
}

private void initialiseDetectorsAndSources() {

    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Barcode scanner started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this)
            .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.ALL_FORMATS)
            .build();

    cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(this, barcodeDetector)
            .setRequestedPreviewSize(1920, 1080)
            .setAutoFocusEnabled(true) //you should add this feature
            .build();

    surfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            try {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MovieUpdateDeleteActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    cameraSource.start(surfaceView.getHolder());
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MovieUpdateDeleteActivity.this, new
                            String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            cameraSource.stop();
        }
    });


    barcodeDetector.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<Barcode>() {
        @Override
        public void release() {
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Barcode scanner has been stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
            final SparseArray<Barcode> barcodes = detections.getDetectedItems();
            if (barcodes.size() != 0) {


                txtBarcodeValue.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        if (barcodes.valueAt(0).email != null) {
                            txtBarcodeValue.removeCallbacks(null);
                            intentData = barcodes.valueAt(0).email.address;
                            txtBarcodeValue.setText(intentData);
                            isEmail = true;
                        } else {
                            isEmail = false;
                            intentData = barcodes.valueAt(0).displayValue;
                            txtBarcodeValue.setText(intentData);
                            scanned = intentData;
                            //startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(intentData)));
                            updateMovie();


                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        }
    });
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    cameraSource.release();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    initialiseDetectorsAndSources();
}



/**
 * Fetches single movie details from the server
 */
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
private class FetchMovieDetailsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //Display progress bar
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MovieUpdateDeleteActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Order Details. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpJsonParser httpJsonParser = new HttpJsonParser();
        Map<String, String> httpParams = new HashMap<>();
        httpParams.put(KEY_MOVIE_ID, movieId);
        JSONObject jsonObject = httpJsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                BASE_URL + "get_movie_details.php", "GET", httpParams);
        try {
            int success = jsonObject.getInt(KEY_SUCCESS);
            JSONObject movie;
            if (success == 1) {
                //Parse the JSON response
                movie = jsonObject.getJSONObject(KEY_DATA);
                updateTime = movie.getString(KEY_UPDATE_TIME);
                custOrder = movie.getString(KEY_CUST_ORDER);
                docDateAwal = movie.getString(KEY_DOC_DATEAWAL);
                movieName = movie.getString(KEY_MOVIE_NAME);
                genre = movie.getString(KEY_GENRE);
                dnNo = movie.getString(KEY_DN_NO);
                invNo = movie.getString(KEY_INV_NO);
                remark = movie.getString(KEY_REMARK);
                type = movie.getString(KEY_TYPE);
                year = movie.getString(KEY_YEAR);
                rating = movie.getString(KEY_RATING);
                materialNumber = movie.getString(KEY_MATERIAL_NUMBER);
                materialName = movie.getString(KEY_MATERIAL_NAME);
                carType = movie.getString(KEY_CAR_TYPE);
                dnDateAwal = movie.getString(KEY_DN_DATEAWAL);
                shipDateAwal = movie.getString(KEY_SHIP_DATEAWAL);
                scanned = movie.getString(KEY_SCANNED_TEXT);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //Populate the Edit Texts once the network activity is finished executing
                updateTimeEditText.setText(updateTime);
                custOrderEditText.setText(custOrder);
                docDateAwalEditText.setText(docDateAwal);
                movieNameEditText.setText(movieName);
                genreEditText.setText(genre);
                dnNoEditText.setText(dnNo);
                invNoEditText.setText(invNo);
                remarkEditText.setText(remark);
                typeEditText.setText(type);
                yearEditText.setText(year);
                ratingEditText.setText(rating);
                materialNumberEditText.setText(materialNumber);
                materialNameEditText.setText(materialName);
                carTypeEditText.setText(carType);
                dnDateAwalEditText.setText(dnDateAwal);
                shipDateAwalEditText.setText(shipDateAwal);
                txtBarcodeValue.setText(scanned);
            }
        });
    }


}


/**
 * Checks whether all files are filled. If so then calls UpdateMovieAsyncTask.
 * Otherwise displays Toast message informing one or more fields left empty
 */
private void updateMovie() {


    String STRING_EMPTY = "";
    if (!STRING_EMPTY.equals(updateTimeEditText.getText().toString()) &&
            !STRING_EMPTY.equals(custOrderEditText.getText().toString()) &&
            !STRING_EMPTY.equals(docDateAwalEditText.getText().toString()) &&
            !STRING_EMPTY.equals(movieNameEditText.getText().toString()) &&
            //!STRING_EMPTY.equals(genreEditText.getText().toString()) &&
            !STRING_EMPTY.equals(dnNoEditText.getText().toString()) &&
            !STRING_EMPTY.equals(invNoEditText.getText().toString()) &&
            !STRING_EMPTY.equals(remarkEditText.getText().toString()) &&
            !STRING_EMPTY.equals(typeEditText.getText().toString()) &&
            !STRING_EMPTY.equals(yearEditText.getText().toString()) &&
            !STRING_EMPTY.equals(ratingEditText.getText().toString())&&
            !STRING_EMPTY.equals(materialNumberEditText.getText().toString())&&
            !STRING_EMPTY.equals(materialNameEditText.getText().toString())&&
            !STRING_EMPTY.equals(carTypeEditText.getText().toString())&&
            !STRING_EMPTY.equals(dnDateAwalEditText.getText().toString())&&
            !STRING_EMPTY.equals(shipDateAwalEditText.getText().toString())) {

        updateTime = updateTimeEditText.getText().toString();
        custOrder = custOrderEditText.getText().toString();
        docDateAwal = docDateAwalEditText.getText().toString();
        movieName = movieNameEditText.getText().toString();
        genre = genreEditText.getText().toString();
        dnNo = dnNoEditText.getText().toString();
        invNo = invNoEditText.getText().toString();
       remark = remarkEditText.getText().toString();
        type = typeEditText.getText().toString();
        year = yearEditText.getText().toString();
        rating = ratingEditText.getText().toString();
        materialNumber = materialNumberEditText.getText().toString();
        materialName = materialNameEditText.getText().toString();
        carType = carTypeEditText.getText().toString();
        dnDateAwal = dnDateAwalEditText.getText().toString();
        shipDateAwal = shipDateAwalEditText.getText().toString();
        new UpdateMovieAsyncTask().execute();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MovieUpdateDeleteActivity.this,
                "One or more fields left empty!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }


}
/**
 * AsyncTask for updating a movie details
 */

@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
private class UpdateMovieAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //Display progress bar
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MovieUpdateDeleteActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Updating Order Data. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpJsonParser httpJsonParser = new HttpJsonParser();
        Map<String, String> httpParams = new HashMap<>();

        //Populating request parameters
        httpParams.put(KEY_MOVIE_ID, movieId);
        httpParams.put(KEY_UPDATE_TIME, updateTime);
        httpParams.put(KEY_CUST_ORDER, custOrder);
        httpParams.put(KEY_DOC_DATEAWAL, docDateAwal);
        httpParams.put(KEY_MOVIE_NAME, movieName);
        httpParams.put(KEY_GENRE, genre);
        httpParams.put(KEY_DN_NO, dnNo);
        httpParams.put(KEY_INV_NO, invNo);
        httpParams.put(KEY_REMARK, remark);
        httpParams.put(KEY_TYPE, type);
        httpParams.put(KEY_YEAR, year);
        httpParams.put(KEY_RATING, rating);
        httpParams.put(KEY_MATERIAL_NUMBER, materialNumber);
        httpParams.put(KEY_MATERIAL_NAME, materialName);
        httpParams.put(KEY_CAR_TYPE, carType);
        httpParams.put(KEY_DN_DATEAWAL, dnDateAwal);
        httpParams.put(KEY_SHIP_DATEAWAL, shipDateAwal);
        httpParams.put(KEY_SCANNED_TEXT, scanned);

        JSONObject jsonObject = httpJsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                BASE_URL + "update_movie.php", "POST", httpParams);
        try {
            success = jsonObject.getInt(KEY_SUCCESS);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (success == 1) {
                    //Display success message
                    Toast.makeText(MovieUpdateDeleteActivity.this,
                            "Order Data Updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent i = getIntent();
                    //send result code 20 to notify about movie update
                    setResult(20, i);
                    finish();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MovieUpdateDeleteActivity.this,
                            "You don't make any changes or some error occurred!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

This code results a scanner app that scan (scanned_text) than paste in the scanned_text column in movie_id position.
I want to make this scanner can scan value, and compare with inv_no enterily, if match, paste the value into scanned_text in every rows that matched the value and set the value become TRUE.
The result I want to achieve

Comment: It's easier to understand what you want if you included the related part of the schema and the desired result.

Comment: @Accountantم I already edit my question, hope you understand what I need